# Navigation drawer contents of Moodle 3.2 Boost Theme

Tags: moodle

## How to modify contents within navigation drawer of Moodle 3.2 Boost Theme ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the navigation, you must create a local plugin 'local/your_plugin/lib.php' file.

### Please check this

https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=345598#p1402870

Answer (score 0):

In Moodle 3.2, I successfully done the same using the following snippet

```
<style>

[data-key='home'] { display: none; }            /* Remove "Site home" */

[data-key='calendar'] {display: none; }         /* Remove "Calendar" */

[data-key='5'] {display: none; }                /* Remove "Private files" */

</style>
```

Found on:
https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=180982

Comment: Infact I was looking to develop a local plugin to customize the Nested navigation in Boost theme..